# What languages and frameworks are used by Ask Ubuntu website?

Tags: discussion

I want to know what frameworks and languages were used to build the Ask Ubuntu website.

Well, of course I did a bit of research before asking. The **Inspect Element** suggests that php is extensively used. Apart from PHP, HTML and CSS; What other modules were used in the development process?

Were any additional frameworks used? (Something like Ruby-On-Rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no PHP at all. I'd be curious to know why you think anything in the source code suggests PHP.

It's C#/ASP.NET

You can see the [full Stack Exchange architecture on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network).

Comment: I probably got carried away. Thanks a lot :)